# Highcharts Chart with Two Axis Not Scaling Correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, axis

I'm a bit stumped.  A little new to Highcharts. I have a watered down version of the chart I'm making with the issue I'm seeing.

I have three values on two y-axis.  The second y-axis is linked to the first to ensure they share the same scale.

However, when the first y-axis gets a value much larger than the second, the chart doesn't auto re-size and the data point goes off the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/L8x4a7x1/

In this example, if you look at this series:

```
  {
    name: "Vals 0",
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [10, 200]
  }
```

The value 200 is off the chart, as the scale seems to only care about the spline y-axis.

Any idea why this is the case and what can be done to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an axis is [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo) another it takes the extremes from the master. Since your master (first yAxis) is assigned to splines, you have 12 as max in master axis. So make the y-Axis with largest extremes the master.

```
series: [{
    name: "Vals 0",
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 0,
    data: [10, 200]
}, {
    name: "Vals 1",
    type: 'spline',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [4, 6]
}, {
    name: "Vals 2",
    type: 'spline',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [3, 1]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6evnttmg/

Comment: Awesome, did not know about the yAxis flag. I can set them all to 0 and it renders as expected without having to figure out which category has the highest value.  Cheers